# Using XMLHttpRequest to send Javascript variable to PHP to query MySQL. Not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to query my MySQL database. The Javascript code in my html file is ...

```
<script>
function getGameNumberOfPlays() { 
   var sentValue1 = Number;   
   var xhttp;
   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("gameNumberOfPlays").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", "numberOfPlays.php", true);
   xhttp.send(sentValue1);
}
</script>
```

The 'numberOfPlays.php' code is ...

```
<?php
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';

$conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

$p1 = $_GET['sentValue1'];

$sql= "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `data` WHERE `gameNumber` =  ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $p1);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_array();
echo "$user[0]";
$conn->close();

?>
```

The code above produces 0 in my html page.

However, if I change the code of 'numberOfPlays.php' to ...

```
<?php
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';

$conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

$p1 = $_GET['sentValue1'];

$p2 = 171; // or any number that's in the database

$sql= "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `data` WHERE `gameNumber` =  ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $p2);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_array();
echo "$user[0]";
$conn->close();

?>
```

I get the correct number in my html page so it appears that the coding is OK except for how the variable 'sentValue1' is sent and received.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could let me know how to change the code so that MySQL query works with the variable 'sentValue1'.

The 'gameNumber' column in the database is configured like this ...

[Screenshot of column 'gameNumber'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOBYP.png)

Many thanks.

Comment: Number is a number as a string. I have tried using 'parseInt' in the Javascript to convert it to an integer before sending but that didn't work. I've also tried using 'intval' in the php file to convert it to an integer before it is used by the query but that didn't work either.  When I tried xhttp.send(sentValue1=2); I just got a 0 in the html page rather than the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not send the `sentValue1` in your xhttp request

change:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "numberOfPlays.php", true);
xhttp.send(sentValue1);
```

to:

```
let URL = "numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=<number>"; 
xhttp.open("GET", URL, true); 
xhttp.send();
```

or:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "numberOfPlays.php", true);
xhttp.send(sentValue1=<number>);
```

You can check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sadly it gave a 404 error.

Comment: Can you try this option: 
let URL = "numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=<number>";
xhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
xhttp.send();

Comment: Again thanks you for your suggestion. I'm still getting 0 in the html page.

Comment: My previous comment about the 404 error was incorrect. I should have said I got 0 in the html page. Apologies.

Comment: Can you check the (xhttp) from the network tab (developer tools)?

Comment: In (let URL) case should be like (numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=171) right?

Comment: Network Tab shows for 'numberOfPlays.php' Type: xor and Transfer Size:74B.

Comment: (numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=171) works correctly!

Comment: When I use control.log(typeof sentValue1) and control.log(sentValue1) I get 'string' and 171 respectively.

Comment: `var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("gameNumberOfPlays").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        var sentValue1 = 12;
        var url = "numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=" + sentValue1;
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();`

this worked for me

Comment: In Network Tab the request should be like that (numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=12)

Comment: If you got the right Value of `sentValue1` in PHP code, So you need to work on PHP file not JS code

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/BIjqVq3) code screenshot

Comment: SOLVED!! Thank you so much.  Two things were the key. Your suggestion to use 'var url = "numberOfPlays.php?sentValue1=" + sentValue1;' and having to include 'var sentValue1 = parseInt (Number);' to convert my variable from a string to an integer.